# I can't switch between radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the Code:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male 
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
```

The strange thing is , when I try to switch between radio button, it's being blocked. If I select Male, then I can't change to Female.

[I am using bootstrap, you can see the live result here](http://abi.maxinrui.com/#slide-5)

Then click Survey, you will see it.

Some help please?

**I recheck and I found if I deletet javascript src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"
It will work, but how would that happen? What should I look into next, to fix that bug.**

Comment: That does look problematic. It does work without Bootstrap. What happens if you take out all the slides except for the survey?

Comment: What do you mean, "it's being blocked"?  Where does it appear in that site?

Comment: Check the new URL http://abi.maxinrui.com/#slide-5, try to select male, and then select female, you will see, thanks

Comment: When you click on Male, you can no longer click on Female and vice versa.

Comment: I looked into it, and the radios are not disabled. (intended only as help)

Comment: You probably have a click handler that is stopping propagation and/of preventing the default behavior.

Comment: Looks like a javascript file is missing http://abi.maxinrui.com/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.map

Comment: Note that it works in incognito tab (no extensions enabled) and problem occurs only in normal tab (with extensions enabled). so maybe it's some kind of sorcery with chrome extensions? Also there is no problem in Opera and Firefox.

Comment: @Stichoza the radio buttons do not work in Firefox for me.

Comment: It works without jQuery, but disabling jQuery will disable Bootstrap. Try to put jQuery but not bootstrap.js (keep the .css) so we can know if it comes from jQuery or Bootstrap.

Comment: @BabyAzerty    I did what you said, it works, but why is that? And what's the bad side if I delete bootstrap.js, maybe I stll need it somewhere

Comment: I delete the bootstrap.js then the nav bar will not show when I browse using mobile phone.

Comment: Its looking like the html5shiv.js file you have

Comment: Yes, the solution is not to just kill bootstrap. But obviously, the problem comes from a conflict between libraries. We need to know which one doesn't work along with bootstrap. Also try to comment all your e.preventDefault(); to see if it's one of them that disabled your radio

Comment: This does not work for me in incognito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the div with the class "slide story" specifically to the data-slide attribute:

```
<div class="slide story" id="slide-5" data-slide="5">
  <!--Code -->
</div>
```

You can see here: [Radio buttons stick](http://jsfiddle.net/eyygK/38/)

Removed slide story div:  [Radio buttons work](http://jsfiddle.net/eyygK/39/)